# How to implement a "main menu" ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, listactivity, listadapter

I have an activity that displays a list of "main menu" items. Each list item should start a new activity when clicked. I do this by loading the appropriate activity using it's class name.

Code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = { "AboutUsActivity", "CompanyProfileActivity", "ProductsActivity", "ContactActivity" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        String cheese = classes[position];
        try {
            Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.test." + cheese);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(this, ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Because I'm storing class names in the list, that is what is shown to the user, so it's not very user-friendly. How can I fix this?

For example, instead of showing "AboutUs", how can I make the list show something like "About Us" or "About Company's Name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MenuActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private String[] menuItems = { "About Us", "Company Profile", "Products", "Contact" };
    private String[] menuClassNames = { AboutUsActivity.class.getName(), CompanyProfileActivity.class.getName(), ProductsActivity.class.getName(), ContactActivity.class.getName() };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuItems));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(menuClassNames[position]));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `menuClassNames` a `Class[]`, and then you wouldn't need to go the extra step of loading the class by name.

Comment: This worked great! thank you so much! been bugging the hell outta me!

Comment: can someone explain to me why this is a bad question??? im banned from posting and im not sure why the 2 negative posts? am i missing some rules here???

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 arrays, one for the classes and other one for the names you want to display.